# Pass Type to IQueryable at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to pass type to IQueryable to realize at run time.

Like,

```
//Get type at runtime
Type type = Type.GetType("fully qualified class name");


IQueryable<type> test = // <-returned object of this type
```

Actual problem as below:
Below I am able to get right side object with specific type, but that is not casting to type of query variable. Also I will have known type for query.

```
Dictionary<string, Type> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
                {
                    { "tableName", typeof(tableName) }
                };

//Below I am able to get right side object with specific type, but that is not casting to type of query variable. Also I will have known type for query.
IQueryable<Type> query= EFContext.Set(myDictionary[tableName]).AsQueryable();
```

Later using this query object to select data by passing select/where condition dynamically.

```
   var data = query.Select(x=> new
                {
                    id= x.id,
                    name= x.name .. etc
                }).ToList();
```

Later I need to use this test variable to dynamically query data.

Also please suggest any alternative to resolve this scenario.

Comment: Not like this, no. You can make a generic method but can't tell without context.

Comment: Trying to do this is indicative of a larger problem with your programs structure.  What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: I think you can, but your service layer becomes very complicated because you need to map the type with a repository (table) on the fly. Also, handling the navigation properties gets very complicated.

Comment: Given most of the IQueryable extension methods take an expression of a particular type, it'll get really messy really quickly trying to do anthing with the queryable. If you just want a queryable to return all the entities from the database, it's possible, but you'll might have to use dynamic results, which are equally as messy. How many types are you dealing with? Can you do it another way, e.g. using a switch statement around what type you want?

Comment: @MrZander  Thank you for reply, Added details of problem I am having.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? In your example, `data` is using a static `Select` (e.g. coded into your program, with fixed properties being accessed).

Answer (score 3):

If you have an example of the `IQueryable` type you need, you can use an generic method to capture the type - this one returns a null of the proper type:

```
public static T NullByExample<T>(this T _) where T : class => (T)null;
```

If you have an example of the items returned, you can use an extension like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyByExample<T>(this T _) => Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

Either use `AsQueryable` on the result:

```
var test = EmptyByExample(classObject).AsQueryable();
```

or create an `IQueryable` variant - unfortunately, there isn't really an `IQueryable` equivalent to `Enumerable.Empty`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> EmptyQueryByExample<T>(this T _) => Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();

var test = EmptyQueryByExample(queryObject);
```

Otherwise, as mentioned, you are in the world of reflection, which probably indicates you are doing something wrong. The problem is you will find you can only get `test` to be of type `object` in that case, because the compiler can't know what `type` represents and e.g. `var` is a compile time shorthand, unless you want to use `dynamic` (and you shouldn't do that either).

Answer (score -2):

There are ways to do what you're asking via reflection, but maintainability will be limited.  You're probably better off creating a shared interface to your types and writing a generic method, something like this:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

IQueryable<T> SomeMethod<T>() where T : IMyInterface, new()
{
    var result = new List<T>() { 
        new T() { SomeProperty = "a"}, 
        new T() { SomeProperty = "b"} 
    };
    return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

So a call to the generic method might be:

```
var temp = SomeMethod<MyClass>();
```